# In ASP.NET Boilerplate, why I can't a Index attribute to an entity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to add a Index attribute like this one:

```
[Index("PostRatingIndex")] 
public int Rating { get; set; }
```

But in VS2013 appears as cannot resolve symbol 'Index'.

My entity is in the Core project.

Comment: So it doesn't compile?

Comment: Which version of EF are you using? (the Index attribute was introduced in Entity Framework 6.1.)

Comment: It doesn't compile...

Comment: The reference of EntityFramework is in the project EntityFramework and its 6.1

Answer (score 3):

As pointed by @Zaki it was necessary to add the "Entity Framework" to the MyProject.Core project.
I was only in the MyProject.EntityFramework project.